# Google App Engine Python If Else Usage in Html Template

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, django-templates

I am creating a web site in google app engine using python. Unfortunately, I could not find anything concerning my problem. I have to distinguish a variable according to its content.

For example i am going to send variables like this

```
content = {
       'mail':session.get('user_mail',''),
       'role':'Admin',
       }
render_template(self, 'index.html', content)
```

And i need such kind of code to understand the type of user if it is a 'Login' user or 'Admin' user.

```
{% if role == 'Ordinary' %}
    {{ role }}
{% elif role == 'Admin' %}
    {{ role }}
{% endif %}
```

How can i do this?

Or maybe there is better design that you can suggest me.

Thank you...

Comment: So, what is your problem? What's wrong with what you have posted?

Comment: Why do you want a logout link labeled Login?

Comment: Sorry it is just a link i ll edit it @Gabi Purcaru. The problem is i cannot do such a check on 'role' variable. I want to see if it is 'Login' or 'Admin'. When i used {% if role == 'Login' %} it gives errors about if else usage. In sample codes, the usage of 'if' like this {% if role %}. So how can i make use of this 'if'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `elif` in django templates. Use something like this:

```
{% if role == 'Login' %}
 ... stuff
{% else %}{% if role eq 'Admin' %}
 ... stuff
{% endif %}
```

Or, with `ifequal`:

```
{% ifequal role "Login" %}
 ... stuff
{% else %}{% ifequal role "Admin" %}
 ... stuff
{% endifequal %}
```

Comment: TemplateSyntaxError: 'if' statement improperly formatted it gives such an error.

Comment: @gurkan try to use the second version

Answer (score 4):

Put the logic in your view function:

```
content = {
   'mail':session.get('user_mail',''),
   'role':'Admin',
   'show_role':True,
   }
```

or

```
content = {
   'mail':session.get('user_mail',''),
   'role':'YetAnther',
   'show_role':False,
   }
```

Then your template is simply

```
{% if show_role %}{{role}}{% endif %}
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid this but if there is no other way around I think I am going to continue with this. Thank you..

Comment: Why avoid it?  It is how the framework is supposed to be used.

Comment: The "role" content actually comes from datastore. So if I add a new userRole to datastore then I have to change my logic accordingly.

Comment: @gurkan: You can change your logic in one of two places -- the template or the view function.  The *meaning* of the role is properly part of the application, not part of the presentation.  The application view function provides a "show_role" flag because the application has decided to show or not show the role.  The template just presents the data with no decision-making and no application-specific rules.  Indeed the "show_role" flag could be used to pick a style rather than display content.